# Excel Recorded Formula Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have put a excel formula in one of the cells and recorded it. Bow when i try applying same formula by running the recorded VBA codes, it gives me an error:

`Error 1004,Application defined or object defined error`

Please help.

Macro Code:

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-7]=""Pay"",IF(AND(RC[-1]=""APAC"",TEXT(RC[-4],""HH:MM:SS"")=""10:00:00""),IF(RC[-2]<=1000000000,""Processor"",IF(AND(RC[-2]>=1000000000,RC[-2]<=1500000000),""Processor"",IF(AND(RC[-2]>=1500000000,RC[-2]<=2000000000),""Processor"",IF(AND(RC[-2]>2000000000),""Processor"",""UnCategorised"")))),IF(AND(RC[-1]=""NON APAC"",TEXT(RC[-4],""HH:MM:SS"")=""12:00:00""),I" & _
        "<=1000000000,""Processor"",IF(AND(RC[-2]>=1000000000,RC[-2]<=1500000000),""Processor"",IF(AND(RC[-2]>=1500000000,RC[-2]<=2000000000),""Processor"",IF(AND(RC[-2]>2000000000),""Processor"",""UnCategorised"")))),""-"")),IF(RC[-2]<=1000000000,""Processor"",IF(AND(RC[-2]>=1000000000,RC[-2]<=1500000000),""Processor"",IF(AND(RC[-2]>=1500000000,RC[-2]<=2000000000),""Process" & _
        "ND(RC[-2]>2000000000),""Processor"",""UnCategorised"")))))"
    Range("H3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you supply your vba code you used?

Comment: @LukeHolmwood Am unable to paste the code here..  it says too long

Comment: edit your question and paste the code there

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using a recorded macro to do this? Why won't copy-paste do the job? As for your error you appear to be missing an `A` at the start of your third formula line, whether that's the cause of your error or not I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Aiken coz formula is to be applied to a range of cells as part of the code

Comment: @user2466447 You'll need to check over your formula string, from the looks of it there are some syntax errors there and I'm guessing you split it onto multiple lines manually. There's definitely some text missing between the second and third lines of the string.

Comment: Comment on behalf of @thepurpledongle: It probably can't find the cells, for example if you're on sheet2 and run the code that was written to work on sheet1 or you've locked a cell etc. This has some great explanations that will definitely help if not with this with your coding going forwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros